# Passing arguments to event listener for unity toggles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I am creating toggles dynamically based on a JSON response, and then adding a listener to each toggle. Right now, each time I click the toggle, it successfully calls the `SomeListener` function. However, I am only able to pass the value of the toggle (`true` or `false`), and ideally I would like to be able to pass both the value of the toggle and an extra argument (`student._id`) to the listener.

```
foreach(var student in students) {
        GameObject studentObject = (GameObject) Instantiate(StudentAttendancePreFab, currentPos, transform.rotation);
        studentObject.GetComponent<AttendanceItem> ().studentId = student._id;
        studentObject.GetComponent<Toggle> ().isOn = student.attending;
        studentObject.GetComponent<Toggle> ().onValueChanged.AddListener(SomeListener);


        //is there some way to do this?
        //studentObject.getComponent<Toggle> ().onValueChanged.AddListener(SomeListener, student._id);
}
```

Listener for each toggle.

```
void SomeListener (bool isClicked) {
    Debug.Log(isClicked);
}

//is there some way to do this?
//void SomeListener(bool isClicker, string studentId) {
    //something
//}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
studentObject.GetComponent<Toggle> ().onValueChanged.AddListener((id)=> SomeListener(student._id));
```

and

```
void SomeListener (float id) {
    Debug.Log("Student id?:"+id);
}
```

these are called lambda expressions, and you can find more info about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: But that loses the bool value.

Comment: (x,y) => doSomething(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it **directly** but here is a way to do it. Try the following (I haven't tested it, but you will get the idea). You will have to declare a public field to your student class of type UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction so as to store a reference to the action related to your student and remove the listener later if you need to.

```
foreach(var student in students) {
        // ..
        string id = student._id ;
        student.listener = MyStudentListener( id ) ;
        studentObject.GetComponent<Toggle> ().onValueChanged.AddListener(student.listener);
}

// ...

private UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<bool> MyStudentListener( string id )
{
     return (val) => SomeListener( val, id ) ;
}

void SomeListener(bool isClicker, string studentId) {
    // something
}}
```

---

Note : The MyStudentListener function can be omitted if you want :

```
 student.listener = (val) => SomeListener( val, id ) ;
```